# Power Shell server live ping status

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Good Day!

I work with multiple clients and one of my clients have their own toll that displays live server ping stats and this is very helpful during patching activity because of followed reboots etc. I want to design a tool like this or any other tool or means where I can see live ping stats of servers in my Domain. Can I do it using Power Shell by any chance? Is there a way that I could refresh my Power Shell page or the output HTML page which updates the ping stats of respective servers please! I have no clue about programming languages but I want to do this as my pet project and I cannot ask my client about all these details. Help is very much appreciated!

Thanks guys, I have tried below two codes:

```
param(
[int]$waitseconds = 3
)

while($true) {
$servers = Get-Content .\servers.txt
$collection = $()

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Down" 
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus

}
$collection | out-gridview; sleep $waitseconds
}
```

This gives me output in a grid view and it also successfully refreshes the output but the new refreshed output is being presented in a new grid view window. I cannot afford opening numerous windows. So I have tried below code:

```
param(
[int]$waitseconds = 3
)

while($true) {
$servers = Get-Content .\servers.txt
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Down" 
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus

}
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-WindowStyle -NoNewWindow -Command &{ $collection | out-gridview; sleep $waitseconds; exit }" -Wait
}
```

This code is not at all giving gridview output, it simply displays ping stats in shell itself but able to refresh.

I have tried below code too with -NoNewWWindow at the end and this gives output one time and then closes:

```
param(
[int]$waitseconds = 3
)

while($true) {
$servers = Get-Content .\servers.txt
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Down" 
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus

}
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-WindowStyle -Command &{ $collection | out-gridview; sleep $waitseconds; exit }" -Wait -NoNewWindow
}
```

Help me with any modifications to my 1st code so that the grid view does not open for every refresh please!

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for programming / scripting issues.
But yes powershell can provide pings and talk to Active Directory. Powershell can use almost everything that is in the .NET Framework. 
If you have a Script / programming issue please post :). Just remeber Stackoverflow is not a code writing service :)

Comment: Powershell ping has been covered many times before, have your tried the searchbox at the top of the page? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+ping

Comment: Guys I have tried and added my code, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$collection | out-gridview
sleep $waitseconds
(Get-Process -id $PID).CloseMainWindow()
```